# Gosper's identity for the golden ratio: $\frac{2^{2/5}\sqrt{5} \, \Gamma(1/5)^4}{\Gamma(1/10)^2 \,\Gamma(3/10)^2} = \phi$

Tags: gamma-function, golden-ratio, constants

Towards the end of a talk by Knuth (one of his Christmas talks, maybe the one from 2017), he mentioned in passing the following identity communicated to him by Bill Gosper (without proof, IIRC):

$$\frac{2^{2/5}\sqrt{5} \, \Gamma(1/5)^4}{\Gamma(1/10)^2 \,\Gamma(3/10)^2} = \phi$$

where $\phi = (1 + \sqrt{5})/2 \approx 1.61803398874989$ is the golden ratio, and $\Gamma$ is the [gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Gamma_function&oldid=927285811) (extension of the factorial function).

Trying it numerically, e.g. with a computer algebra system like Sage, it seems to hold:

[image: sage]

How could one prove this?

Comment: have you checked https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_the_gamma_function in particular the "Products" section.

Comment: @WhatsUp I'm not sure that page particularly helps, there is surprisingly no closed form listed for $\Gamma\left(\frac15\right)$. Though it does list the relation in "Products", under "Other rational relations include".

Comment: @Jam I don't understand your comment. You found that formula on the wiki page I linked, and you probably also saw that there's a reference there, which is a pdf file containing a proof of the formula. Why aren't you sure that page helps? Note that we don't need a closed formula for $\Gamma(\frac15)$ (and there probably isn't one).

Comment: @WhatsUp Ah, I didn't see the reference. Thank you.

Comment: @WhatsUp Thanks for the reference; I looked at the section and it's great to see some very similar identities. But I don't see this exact identity there (even in the PDFs cited as reference)... if you can post an answer with the proof or pointing to it that will be great.

Comment: In the "Products" section, find the sentence "Other rational relations include" and it's the last formula in that sentence (you'll have to square it, though).

Comment: @WhatsUp Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

(As no one posted an answer, summarizing what I learned from the comments.)

Following up on the reference given by [user @WhatsUp](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/256378/whatsup) in [the comments on the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3455108/gospers-identity-for-the-golden-ratio#comment7102535_3455108), the Wikipedia article on “Particular values of the gamma function”, has in [its section on products](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Particular_values_of_the_gamma_function&oldid=918133313#Products), as the last item under “Other rational relations include”, the relation

$$\frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^2}{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{10}\right)\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{10}\right)} = \frac{\sqrt{1+\sqrt{5}}}{2^{\tfrac{7}{10}}\sqrt[4]{5}}$$

which when squared would give

$$\frac{\Gamma(1/5)^4}{\Gamma(1/10)^2\Gamma(3/10)^2} = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2^{7/5}\sqrt{5}}$$

which is what the question asks for.

The reference given on Wikipedia for this relation, namely the paper [“Expressions for values of the gamma function”](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0403510v1.pdf) by Raimundas Vidūnas (seems to be [published](https://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/kyushujm/59/2/59_2_267/_pdf) in Kyushu Journal of Mathematics, 2005, Vol 59, pp 267–283; [DOI](https://doi.org/10.2206/kyushujm.59.267)), does not seem to have this relation exactly.

(It's an interesting question how the relation got onto Wikipedia then. Looking at the edit history of the Wikipedia page, it appears that in February 2018 someone [added](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Particular_values_of_the_gamma_function&diff=826519473&oldid=808102781) it to the Wikipedia page, citing Knuth's 2017 lecture, as I did in the question here. The edit was immediately [undone](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Particular_values_of_the_gamma_function&diff=826524994&oldid=826519473) less than an hour later. Then a week later the user “WorstUsernameEver” [restored](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Particular_values_of_the_gamma_function&diff=next&oldid=826524994) it as a conjecture, and the next day found that it can be obtained by multiplying together two formulae from Vidūnas's paper. As I was typing below...)

However, the paper contains (section 2, page 3), among others, the expressions:

$$Γ(1/10) = \frac{\sqrt \phi}{\sqrt\pi 2^{7/10}} Γ(1/5)\,Γ(2/5) \tag 1$$

and

$$Γ(3/10) = \frac{\sqrt \pi \phi^⋆}{2^{3/5}\sqrt5} Γ(1/5)\,Γ(2/5)^{−1} \tag 2$$

where $\phi = 5 + \sqrt5$ and $\phi^⋆ = 5 - \sqrt{5}$.

Multiplying these two together gives

$$Γ(1/10)Γ(3/10) = \frac{\sqrt{5+\sqrt{5}}(5-\sqrt{5})}{2^{13/10}\sqrt5}Γ(1/5)^2$$

and so

$$\frac{Γ(1/5)^2}{Γ(1/10)Γ(3/10)} = \frac{2^{13/10}\sqrt5}{\sqrt{5+\sqrt{5}}(5-\sqrt{5})} \stackrel{?}{=} \frac{\sqrt{1+\sqrt{5}}}{2^{7/10}\sqrt[4]{5}}$$

and the algebra seems to work out.

(TODO: Understand the paper enough to prove $(1)$ and $(2)$.)

Answer (score 3):

The identity can be proven by using two classic tools:
the [Legendre duplication formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_theorem)
$${\Gamma(2z)\over\Gamma(z)}
={\Gamma(z+1/2)\over2^{1-2z}\sqrt\pi},$$
and [Euler’s reflection formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula)
$$\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z)
={\pi\over\sin(\pi z)}.$$
Let's begin with some housekeeping. Rearranging the original identity,
it suffices to prove that
$${\Gamma(1/10)\over\Gamma(1/5)}{\Gamma(3/10)\over\Gamma(1/5)}
={2^{1/5}5^{1/4}\over\sqrt\phi},$$
where $\phi=(1+\sqrt5)/2$ is the golden ratio.
The first fraction on the left yields immediately to the
Legendre duplication formula:
$${\Gamma(1/10)\over\Gamma(1/5)}
={2^{4/5}\sqrt\pi\over\Gamma(3/5)}.$$
The second fraction needs a little coaxing — we rewrite it a little,
apply the Legendre duplication formula, then Euler’s reflection formula:
$$\begin{align*}
{\Gamma(3/10)\over\Gamma(1/5)}
&={\Gamma(3/10)\over\Gamma(2/5)}{\Gamma(2/5)\over\Gamma(1/5)} \\
&={\Gamma(3/10)\over\Gamma(2/5)}{\Gamma(7/10)\over2^{3/5}\sqrt\pi} \\
&={1\over\Gamma(2/5)2^{3/5}\sqrt\pi}{\pi\over\sin(3\pi/10)}.
\end{align*}$$
Since $\sin(3\pi/10)=\phi/2$, we deduce that
$${\Gamma(3/10)\over\Gamma(1/5)}
={2^{2/5}\sqrt\pi\over\Gamma(2/5)\phi}.$$
Putting it all together now, with one more application of
Euler’s reflection formula:
$$\begin{align*}
{\Gamma(1/10)\over\Gamma(1/5)}{\Gamma(3/10)\over\Gamma(1/5)}
&={2^{4/5}\sqrt\pi\over\Gamma(3/5)}{2^{2/5}\sqrt\pi\over\Gamma(2/5)\phi} \\
&={2^{6/5}\pi\over\phi}{\sin(2\pi/5)\over\pi}
\end{align*}$$
Conveniently, we have $\sin(2\pi/5)=5^{1/4}\sqrt\phi/2$, and so we are done.

#### Appendix: How do you compute weird sine values?

Firstly, one can verify
$$\sin(5x)=16\sin^5x-20\sin^3x+5\sin x,$$
by using, say, [de Moivre’s formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula).
Setting $x=\pi/10$ and writing $y=\sin x$, we get
$$16y^5-20y^3+5y-1=0.$$
Now the coefficients add to zero, which tells us that $y=1$ is a root,
so we may factor out $(y-1)$ to get
$$16y^4+16y^3-4y^2-4y+1=0.$$
This turns out to be
$$(4y^2+2y-1)^2=0,$$
and so
$$y=\sin\Bigl({\pi\over10}\Bigr)={\sqrt5-1\over4}$$
(we reject the negative solution to the quadratic,
as $\sin(\pi/10)$ must be positive).

From here, it is easy to obtain the values of sine that we used earlier.
We have
$$\begin{align*}
\sin\Bigl({3\pi\over10}\Bigr)
&=3\sin\Bigl({\pi\over10}\Bigr)-4\sin^3\Bigl({\pi\over10}\Bigr) \\
&=3\Bigl({\sqrt5-1\over4}\Bigr)-4\Bigl({\sqrt5-1\over4}\Bigr)^3 \\
&={3\sqrt5\over4}-{3\over4}-{5\sqrt5-15+3\sqrt5-1\over16} \\
&={1\over4}+{\sqrt5\over4} \\
&=\phi/2.
\end{align*}$$
Similarly, we have
$$\sin\Bigl({2\pi\over5}\Bigr)
=\sin\Bigl({\pi\over2}-{\pi\over10}\Bigr)
=\sin\Bigl({\pi\over2}\Bigr)\cos\Bigl({\pi\over10}\Bigr)
-\cos\Bigl({\pi\over2}\Bigr)\sin\Bigl({\pi\over10}\Bigr)
=\cos\Bigl({\pi\over10}\Bigr),$$
and so
$$\begin{align*}
\sin\Bigl({2\pi\over5}\Bigr)
=\cos\Bigl({\pi\over10}\Bigr)
&=\sqrt{1-\sin^2\Bigl({\pi\over10}\Bigr)} \\
&=\sqrt{1-\Bigl({\sqrt5-1\over4}\Bigr)^2} \\
&=\sqrt{1-{5-2\sqrt5+1\over16}} \\
&=\sqrt{5+\sqrt5\over8} \\
&={1\over2}\sqrt{\sqrt{5}(1+\sqrt5)\over2} \\
&=5^{1/4}\sqrt\phi/2.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Also, it's worth noting that the fraction ${\Gamma(1/10)\Gamma(3/10)\over\Gamma(1/5)^2}$ can be expressed using the Gauss hypergeometric function as ${}_2F_1(1/10,1/10;3/10;1)$; see for example Equation (5.92) of Graham, Knuth, and Patashnik, _Concrete Mathematics_.